# When visiting cypress.io, I get Minified React error #418

Tags: cypress

Created an empty skeleton project using `npx cypress open`, created the file, plugged in the URL https://cypress.io/ and it is throwing an error upon executing the test. "Minified react error". Anyone else noticing this?

Cypress Version: 11.1.0
MacOs Version 12.6.1 Monterey
Chrome Version 107

```
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(uncaught exception)Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
(xhr)GET 200 https://scout.salesloft.com/i
(fetch)POST 200 https://sentry.io/api/1387440/store/?sentry_key=a50ef5d924b84c02868bd16788d4f3b5&sentry_version=7
2
(xhr)POST 200 /j/collect?v=1&_v=j98&a=374461605&t=event&ni=1&_s=1&dl=https://www.cypress.io/&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=JavaScript End to End Testing Framework | cypress.io testing tools&sd=30-bit&sr=1792x1120&vp=1000x660&je=0&ec=Clearbit&ea=API Resolution&el=Reveal API - GTM&_u=YADAAEABAAAAACAAI~&jid=901020075&gjid=271599248&cid=897255695.1668729917&tid=UA-59606812-1&_gid=1763388137.1668729918&_r=1&gtm=2wgb90K8R2FS5&z=2134669599
(xhr)POST 200 https://www.google-
```

Comment: You get that if you just visit the website in a browser, too; it's nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for confirming; however, it is failing my test.. is there a way I can set it to ignore this so that the test does not fail?

Answer (score 2):

There's a section in the documentation [Uncaught Exceptions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Uncaught-Exceptions) that explains how to turn off the error.

Basic:

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

but it gives several examples, so please make sure to use one that fits your scenario.

Comment: I can now run the tests without the exception. Thank you!